# How do I prevent two different programs running at the same time?

Tags: windows-10, cpu-usage, task-manager

I have two quality programs Macrium reflect, and Zoomtext 2021 on the same laptop. Both work fine separately, but if Zt.exe and ReflectMonitor.exe are running simultaneously CPU usage is too high. How do I tell Windows an if then statement like "If Zt.exe is running, then don't run ReflectMonitor.exe?

Comment: How are they launched? Manually? A script (batch/PowerShell) that checks for the process of the other and if not running launches the application seems the best option.

Comment: E.g.as a simple example, the one line PowerShell: `if(get-Process diskview -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){exit 1}else{&./winobj.exe}` This will only launch Winobj.exe if diskview process isn't running for example.

Comment: Zt.exe launches when I click on the Zoomtext desktop icon. ReflectMonitor.exe seems to sit harmlessly way at the bottom of my task manager is an idle process until Zoomtext is enabled then ReflectMonitor.exe starts arbitrarily using a ton of CPU.

Comment: My current work around is to move ReflectMonitor.exe to the recycle bin, and then restore it right before creating a Macrium Reflect backup, but I really need a more elegant solution.